# Storing database in NSCachesDirectory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I want to keep my database in NSCachesDirectory. 
Will it gets deleted without i am doing it programmatically? 
Is there any possibility to happen this? 
Please let me know. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The Caches directory will not be backed up and will probably be empty after a restore of the device. Also, the OS is free to delete items from the Caches directory at any time (e.g. if it needs disk space).

Comment: Thank you so much Ole for your response. :-)